# An exponential recurrence

Tags: recurrence-relations

Is there any way to solve the recurrence

$$x[n+1]=(x[n]+1)2^{x[n]+1}-1$$

I know how to solve recurrences with z-transforms, but it doesn't look like that technique will yield anything useful here.  I have a feeling I'll be able to work around this if worse comes to worse, but a solution to this recurrence would simplify things greatly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First simplify the recurrence by defining $\ y[n]:=x[n]+1\ $ then you want :
$$y[n+1]=y[n]\,2^{y[n]}$$
Let's set $\ u[n]:=\log_2(y[n])\ $ to get smaller values then the $\log$ in base $2$ of the last recurrence will give :
$$u[n+1]=u[n]+y[n]=u[n]+2^{u[n]}$$
This fast growing sequence appears as sequence [A034797](https://oeis.org/A034797) of OEIS (when $a[0]=1$ at least) with reference to this paper ['Sloping Binary Numbers: A New Sequence Related to the Binary Numbers'](http://arXiv.org/abs/math/0505295v1) from Applegate, Cloitre, Deléham and Sloane (see around $(29)$).

Hoping this helped,

Comment: By the looks of things, something is known of the recurrence then, but I don't see a closed form of it anywhere.  Looks like it's time to work on that Plan B then.  Thanks.

Comment: @Mike: you are welcome!